# Hide breadcrumb from CMIS views

Tags: breadcrumbs

We're running Drupal 7.65 and Alfresco 5.2.4. We've the ability to display CMIS content (hosted in Alfresco) by fetching a URI like: `https://domain.com/cmis/browser?id=<node_ID>`. Doing so allow users who doesn't have access to Alfresco to download a file (if `node_ID` refers to a file) or browse the content of a directory (if `node_ID` refers to a directory).

**Issue:** sharing a directory via this method allow users to navigate the whole content of Alfresco by navigating the breadcrumb.

[image: example of CMIS content from Alfresco display by Drupal]

**We'd like to remove this breadcrumb**, could you recommend ways to do it ?

Here's what we've been thiking at:

- Ideally, find a Drupal/Alfresco setting that allow us to restrict display
- Comment out the line(s) responsible of displaying this breadcrumb inside Drupal' source code
- less ideally, filter the DOM through JS (`document.getElementById('cmis-breadcrumb').innerHTML = ''`)

---

Apologies for my English and the lack of knowledge about CMIS and Drupal

---

**edit 19/01/2021**: I believe I've found the module & the function responsible for the breadcrumb: https://git.drupalcode.org/project/cmis/-/blob/7.x-1.x/cmis_browser/cmis_browser.theme.inc#L125

Comment: The goal is just to hide the breadcrumb, not to actually restrict access to the files?

Comment: Yes indeed, we'd like to remove the breadcrumb

Answer (score 1):

[CMIS Browser](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/cmis/-/tree/7.x-1.x/cmis_browser), a submodule of [CMIS API](https://www.drupal.org/project/cmis), handles CMIS links. We are using CMIS API v7.x.x.

Here's the function responsible for the breadcrumb:

```php
# cmis/cmis_browser/cmis_browser.theme.inc #125

function theme_cmis_browser_browse_breadcrumb($variables) {

  $next_img = theme('image', array('path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'cmis_browser') .'/images/next.gif'));
  $contents = '';
  $currentpath = '';

  $contents .= '<div id="cmis-breadcrumb">';
  if (!empty($_GET['type']) && $_GET['type'] == 'popup') {
    $contents .= l('Root', 'cmis/browser'. $currentpath, array('query' => array('type' => 'popup', 'caller' => $_GET['caller'])));
  }
  else {
    $contents .= l('Root', 'cmis/browser'. $currentpath);
  }

  $currentpath = '';
  foreach ($variables['bcarray'] as $space) {
    $contents .= $next_img .' ';
    $currentpath .= '/'. $space;
    if (!empty($_GET['type']) && $_GET['type'] == 'popup') {
      $pagelink = l($space, 'cmis/browser'. $currentpath, array('query' => array('type' => 'popup', 'caller' => $_GET['caller'])));
    }
    else {
      $pagelink = l($space, 'cmis/browser'. $currentpath);
    }
    $contents .= $pagelink;
  }

  $contents .= '</div>';

  return $contents;
}
```

Our workaround is simply to return an empty `<div>` earlier:

```php
function theme_cmis_browser_browse_breadcrumb($variables) {
  return '<div id="removed-breadcrumb"></div>';
  
  .....
}
```

Be careful since it's not a persistent solution.